# How to put two buttons in same line

Tags: html, css

I need help with the displayed image below. The two buttons "edit and back" button is not being displayed on line. The code for both the button is as below. They are both inside the same `<td></td>`

```
<tr><td>
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>"/>
  <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit"/>
  <?php
    //create a  back button that takes user back to referer url on click
    if (isset($HTTP_REFERER)) {
      echo '<a href="$HTTP_REFERER"><img src="images/buttons/back.gif" alt="back"></a>';
    } else {
      echo '<a href="javascript:history.back()"><img src="images/buttons/back.gif" alt="back"></a>';
    }
  ?>
</td></tr>
```

I can't upload the image directly so here is the link where I uploaded the image
image source: http://i39.tinypic.com/2miab.png

Comment: you mean the css of the div these elements are inside?

Comment: WHatever is relevant, you are clearly applying styles to your buttons and cells. If you didn't the buttons would be in the same line ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well I noticed that some solutions might work differently in different browsers
putting your buttons in another small table without any attributes will keep them in a single line

```
<table><tr> <td><input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo
$token; ?>"/></td> <td> <?php
//create a  back button that takes user back to referer url on click
if (isset($HTTP_REFERER)) {
echo '<a href="$HTTP_REFERER"><img1 src="images/buttons/back.gif" alt="back"></a>';
} else {
echo '<a href="javascript:history.back()"><img1 src="images/buttons/back.gif" alt="back"></a>';
}
?> </td> </tr></table>
```

hope this is what you wanted

Comment: Thanks, I have separated the table of the buttons and now it is working as expected. Thanks a lot vadim.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit"/>
</td>
<td>
 <?php
    //create a  back button that takes user back to referer url on click
    if (isset($HTTP_REFERER)) {
        echo '<a href="$HTTP_REFERER"><img src="images/buttons/back.gif" alt="back"></a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="javascript:history.back()"><img src="images/buttons/back.gif" alt="back"></a>';
    }
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: The given code does work but that will separate the buttons because of the separate table data. Here is what the output with the above given code:
http://i43.tinypic.com/6xyh68.png